# Происхождение супплетивов

Tags: словообразование

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какая-нибудь информация о природе явления **супплетивизма**?

Comment: ***Я не знаю, что делать с этим вопросом.*** Он постоянно всплывает для проверки, а единственный "верный" (с точки зрения вопрошающего) ответ удален автором. На всякий случай сообщу, что по всем имеющимся признакам автора интересует не информация вообще (ибо конкретные примеры не названы), а о ***литературе, источниках, где такая информация может содержаться***. С этой оговоркой вопрос вполне корректен, закрытию не подлежит. Как быть?!

Answer (score 1):

Есть известный труд Соломона Давидовича Кацнельсона - "К генезису номинативного предложения" (1936).
[Глава о супплетивах](http://crecleco.seriot.ch/textes/KACNELSON36/I.html)
Почитайте, интересно.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!Нашла ответы на некоторые вопросы и подтвердила некоторые предположения!

Answer (score 0):

Каких конкретно?
Если вас интересует супплетивизм вообще, то обычно его, как и почти всякую грамматическую "неправильность", соотносят с архаизмами. Но, естественно, бывает и по-другому,  надо разбираться с конкретными случаями.

Comment: Проанализировали учебники русского языка, нашли супплетивы, пытаемся разобраться на уровне их особенностей.